# FFMPEG Combining images to video and streaming in one command line

Tags: linux, video, filter, ffmpeg, streaming

Currently, using ffmpeg, I am using two commands on my Terminal to:

1) create a video from a bunch of images:

`ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -s 1920x1080 -i rotated-pano_frame%05d_color_corrected_gradblend.jpg -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4`

2) stream the video to a udp address:

```
ffmpeg -re -i test.mp4 -c copy -f flv udp://127.0.0.1:48550
```

How can I combine these two commands, into one single ffmpeg command?

A concern I have is that it takes a couple of minutes to generate the video from the images. Therefore, these commands have to happen serially, whereby the second command waits a few minutes for the first command to be completed, before it ensues.

Answer (score 0):

Just add && between the two commands. This will execute the second command if the first executes successfully.

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -s 1920x1080 -i rotated-pano_frame%05d_color_corrected_gradblend.jpg -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4 && ffmpeg -re -i test.mp4 -c copy -f flv udp://127.0.0.1:48550
```

Comment: Thank you, tried your suggestion and the first command of creating a video was successful. 

However, I am encountering an error with the second command:
" [flv @ 0x7fa2ba800000] video stream discovered after head already parsed "

And the streaming end therefore remains unsuccessful.