# Creating Video and Streaming Command Line

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, ffmpeg, streaming

Currently, using ffmpeg, I am using two commands on my Terminal to:

1) create a video from a bunch of images:

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -s 1920x1080 -i rotated-pano_frame%05d_color_corrected_gradblend.jpg -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
```

2) stream the video to a udp address:

```
ffmpeg -re -i test.mp4 -c copy -f flv udp://127.0.0.1:48550
```

I am trying to combine both these instructions into one command line instruction, using &&, as suggested in the answer to [a previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45060462/ffmpeg-combining-images-to-video-and-streaming-in-one-command-line):

```
ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -s 1920x1080 -i rotated-pano_frame%05d_color_corrected_gradblend.jpg -vcodec libx264 -crf 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4 \
&& ffmpeg -re -i test.mp4 -c copy -f flv udp://127.0.0.1:48550
```

but am encountering an error which prevents streaming:

```
[flv @ 0x7fa2ba800000] video stream discovered after head already parsed.
```

Thoughts on a different command line syntax to join the two instructions, different ffmpeg instruction (filters perhaps?), and why I am getting the error?

Comment: This looks like more of an ffmpeg issue than a bash one. Try https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20094/ffmpeg-replay-input-to-output-giving-errors

Comment: Do you need to create the file on disk?

Comment: Possible cross-site duplicate: https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20094/ffmpeg-replay-input-to-output-giving-errors

Comment: Why do you use UDP instead of RTP? @Brindha Kanniah

Comment: For a faster transmission rate as the receiving client doesn´t check for transmission errors with UDP. @SalihKaragoz